# Delay and views errors with AdMob interstitial ads

Tags: admob

I have AdMob ads working in my app since a long time ago. But recently I noticed a problem: interstitial ads are shown with a delay of about 1 second (yes, I load them before show, and I only show them if they are loaded). And when I close them, the Activity doesn't work properly (views are not responding correctly).

This is happening in my published app (last updated two months ago). And it started happening yesterday, so this must be an issue from AdMob.

Anyone knows anything about it?

Comment: This has started happening with me and I have opened a question myself:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595325/admob-interstitial-with-viewpager-issues-after-dismiss

Even I have noticed this recently and it didn't happen before. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I hope AdMob fixes it soon